# serializer null in JdbcExecutionContextDao

Tags: spring, nullpointerexception, batch-processing

I am using spring-batch-core 2.2.6 and spring-batch-admin-manager 1.3.0.M1. In spring-batch-admin-manager's own execution-context.xml 
there is a scheduled job

```
<task:scheduled-tasks>
<task:scheduled ref="jobService" method="removeInactiveExecutions" fixed-delay="$
{batch.job.service.reaper.interval}
"/>
</task:scheduled-tasks>
```

which looks for inactive executions and removes it. We have a long running batch job which takes more than 1 min.

When removeInactiveExecutions in SimpleJobService runs it tries to get the execution entry from database and it is failing with NullPointerException. 
While failing it closes the connection and if the main batch job is using same connection it fails with connection already closed error.

I see there are couple of JIRA's raised on spring board BATCH-2155 and BATCH-2183 for this. But it was closed give either being invalid or working as expected as resolution.

I could also see someone has tried to fix this issue in

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch-admin/pull/17

https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/pull/256/commits

but this is still not available in release.
This was also discussed on old spring forum without any resolution

http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/batch/744935-spring-batch-admin-ui-not-initializing-executioncontextdao-properly

This is happening because serializer is null in JdbcExecutionContextDao and fails with NullPointerException.